# Import Freebase into cassandra

Tags: cassandra, freebase

I m new to cassandra and freebase. I was wondering if it is possible to import data from freebase into cassandra and query on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [datadump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) and then create program that will insert data to Cassandra. However, cassandra is not suitable for searching like full text search engines do, it can only do very basic queries. So maybe you should use elasticsearch or some other search engine for this.

Comment: thanks for mentioning elasticsearch. That may be a better choice to start with.